# Angularjs x-editable table with computed column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

Working in angular x-editable inline table. I would like to have additional columns which are computed values based on other columns.

Once the user added a row, it should be updated to the local scope array based on index. However I could not able to see the computed column `MRPVATAmount, COSTVATAmount` values. It shows the data that bound only to the `x-editable` fields.

How to get the computed values like `COSTVATAmount`onbeforesave event, i.e in **$scope.savePurchaseItem?**

[**PLUNKER DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/r3KizBEVik4hFkGsdO2r?p=preview)

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <div class="purchase-order-container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="savePurchase()">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="DiscountPercent" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Disc%</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <input name="DiscountPercent" type="number" step="any" min="0" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-model="purchaseHeader.DiscountPercent">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="row" style="overflow:auto">
            <div class="purchase-entry-data">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed purchase-entry">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Batch</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th>Free</th>
                            <th>Pack</th>
                            <th>MRP Abt</th>
                            <th>MRP</th>
                            <th>Cost</th>
                            <th>Free Disc</th>
                            <th>VAT%</th>
                            <th>Disc%</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>VAT Amt</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr ng-repeat="order in purchaseOrders">
                        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                            <!-- form -->
                            <form editable-form name="rowform" onbeforesave="savePurchaseItem($data, order.Id, rowform)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="inserted == order">
                                <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
                                    <em class="fa fa-save"></em>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="cancelOrder()" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
                                    <em class="fa fa-times"></em>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                            <div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rowform.$show()">edit</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeProduct($index)">del</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span editable-text="order.BatchNo" e-name="BatchNo" e-form="rowform" e-required>
                        {{ order.BatchNo || '' }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span editable-number="order.Qty" e-style="width:50px" e-min="1" e-step="1" e-name="Qty" e-form="rowform">
                        {{ order.Qty || 1 }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span e-min="0" e-step="1" editable-number="order.FreeQty" e-name="FreeQty" e-style="width:50px" e-form="rowform">
                        {{ order.FreeQty || 0 }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span e-min="1" e-step="1" editable-number="order.Packing" e-name="Packing" e-style="width:50px" e-form="rowform">
                        {{ order.Packing || 1 }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span ng-model="rowform.$data.MRPAbt" style="width:60px" e-name="MRPAbt" e-style="width:60px" e-form="rowform">
                        {{ calculateMRPAbt(rowform.$data) }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span e-step="any" e-min="0" editable-number="order.MRP" e-name="MRP" e-style="width:60px" e-form="rowform">
                        {{ order.MRP || '' }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span e-step="any" e-min="0" editable-number="order.Cost" e-name="Cost" e-style="width:60px" e-form="rowform">
                        {{ order.Cost || '' }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span e-step="any" e-min="0" editable-number="order.FreeDisc" e-name="FreeDisc" e-style="width:40px" e-form="rowform">
                        {{ order.FreeDisc || '' }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span editable-select="order.VAT" e-name="VAT" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="tm.value as tm.text for tm in taxes" e-style="width:40px">
                        {{ showSelectedVAT(order) }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span e-step="any" e-min="0" editable-number="order.DiscountPercentage" e-name="DiscountPercentage" e-style="width:40px" e-form="rowform">
                        {{ order.DiscountPercentage || '' }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span ng-model="rowform.$data.MRPVATAmount" style="width:60px" e-name="MRPVATAmount" e-style="width:60px" e-form="rowform">
                        {{ calculateMRPVATAmount(rowform.$data) }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span ng-model="rowform.$data.COSTVATAmount" style="width:60px" e-name="COSTVATAmount" e-style="width:60px" e-form="rowform">
                        {{ calculateCostVATAmount(rowform.$data) }}
                    </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="addNewProduct()">Add row</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

App.JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap", "xeditable", "ngMockE2E"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
    editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
    $scope.taxes = [{
        value: 5.5,
        text: '5.5'
    }, {
        value: 4,
        text: '4'
    }];
    $scope.purchaseOrders = [];

    $scope.purchaseId = 0;
    $scope.selectedVal = 0;
    $scope.purchaseHeader = {};
    $scope.productMaster = [];
    $scope.inserted = {};

    $scope.savePurchase = function() {


        $scope.purchaseHeader.PurchaseItems = $scope.purchaseOrders;

    }

    $scope.savePurchaseItem = function(data, id, rowform, idx) {
        //data doesnot have MRPVATAmount, COSTVATAmount property. It has only editable data
    }

    $scope.checkProductName = function(data, rowform) {
        debugger;
    }

    $scope.setDiscPercentToAll = function(data, tableform) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tableform.$editables.length; i++) {
            if (tableform.$editables[i].name === 'user.status') {
                tableform.$editables[i].scope.$data = data;

            }
        }
    };
    //$scope.$watch('purchaseHeader.DiscountPercent', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {

    //});
    $scope.addNewProduct = function() {
        $scope.inserted = {
            isNew: true,
            BatchNo: '',
            Qty: 1,
            FreeQty: 0,
            ExpiryDate: '',
            Packing: 1,
            AssortedQty: 0,
            VAT: 4,
            DiscountPercentage: $scope.purchaseHeader.DiscountPercent,
            MRP: 0,
            COSTVATAmount: 0,
            MRPVATAmount: 0

        };

        $scope.purchaseOrders.push($scope.inserted);
    };
    $scope.addNewProduct();
    $scope.removeProduct = function(index) {
        //$scope.users.splice(index, 1);
    };



    $scope.cancelOrder = function() {
        for (var i = $scope.purchaseOrders.length; i--;) {
            var order = $scope.purchaseOrders[i];
            // undelete
            if (order.isDeleted) {
                delete order.isDeleted;
            }
            // remove new 
            if (order.isNew) {
                $scope.purchaseOrders.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    };
    $scope.formatProductNameLabel = function(model) {

        return model;

    };

    $scope.showProductName = function(model) {

        return model.ProdId;

    };

    $scope.getStats = function(q) {
        return $scope.states;

    };

    $scope.showSelectedVAT = function(order) {

        var selected = [];
        selected = $filter('filter')($scope.taxes, {
            Tax: order.VAT
        });

        return selected.length ? selected[0].value : $scope.taxes[0].value;
    };


    $scope.calculateMRPVATAmount = function(order) {
        var amount = (order.Qty * parseFloat(order.MRP)) * (parseFloat(order.VAT) / 100);
        return (isNaN(amount)) ? 0 : amount;
    }

    $scope.calculateCostVATAmount = function(order) {
        var amount = (order.Qty * parseFloat(order.Cost)) * (parseFloat(order.VAT) / 100);
        return (isNaN(amount)) ? 0 : amount;
    }
    $scope.calculateMRPAbt = function(order) {
        var mrpVatAmt = $scope.calculateMRPVATAmount(order);
        var amount = ((order.Qty * parseFloat(order.MRP)) - mrpVatAmt);
        return (isNaN(amount)) ? 0 : amount;
    }


});

// --------------- mock $http requests ----------------------
app.run(function($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/groups').respond([{
        id: 1,
        label: 'user'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        label: 'customer'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        label: 'vip'
    }, {
        id: 4,
        label: 'admin'
    }]);

    $httpBackend.whenPOST(/\/saveUser/).respond(function(method, url, data) {
        data = angular.fromJson(data);
        return [200, {
            status: 'ok'
        }];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$scope.calculateCostVATAmount = function(order) {
    var amount = (order.Qty * parseFloat(order.Cost)) * (parseFloat(order.VAT) / 100);
    order.COSTVATAmount = (isNaN(amount)) ? 0 : amount;
    return order.COSTVATAmount;
  }
```

Otherwise, I don't see how it could know the value of COSTVATAmount since it's not set anywhere.

Comment: My question is about how to get the value in $scope.savePurchaseItem?

Comment: Right, when you change the calculateCostVATAmount like above, in the savePurchaseItem method, `data` has the CostVATAmount updated.

Comment: Not getting, Can you look at my demo link provided and make it work with what you saying?

Comment: It's quite possible I'm misunderstanding what you mean, but here you go : http://plnkr.co/edit/UoXWgnqOVMEwVvHonnqG?p=preview

Comment: It did work. Thanks. I am looking now how to track the changes in the purchaseOrders using unique id. I dont want to use index. All I need is user can start adding row and updating it. While they update, I need to find the right record in `$scope.purchaseOrders` in `savePurchaseItem` method and update it with additional values. Any idea you have it?

Comment: You could do something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/UoXWgnqOVMEwVvHonnqG?p=preview . But if your problem is solved you should mark the answer and create a new question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again. Let me check.

Comment: How to sum row values. (like sum of vat amout)...! If it is possible, anyone help me.....!